Insulation for a bump out bathroom
How should my builder insulate a 5foot by 10 foot bathroom bump out in MA?
I want something safe please.
Thank you.

If you are "bumping out" a bathroom with plumbing, in a cold climate, the primary thing is to insulate Very, Very, Well and be sure that all pipes are on the inside of the insulation. The type of insulation used is far less important. Frozen pipes are bad.

I think my builder said he needed to use some foam insulation. I just don’t want off gassing of chemicals.

Foam is pretty inert once cured. (And for the products I’ve used, it doesn’t offgas much.) If you have exceptional environmental sensitivities, talk to your contractor.

Thanks so much.

Have to second the concern/worry about plumbing and outside walls/floors.  If at all possible, routing the plumbing to inside walls/inside cabinets on outside walls is better.

Thanks so much everyone.

Can anyone recommend a safe insulation? My builder thinks a foam is best.
